# Nginx (HTTP Only) Reverse Proxy Settings in Production

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am playing around with `Nginx` and I successfully set up a simple (for now `HTTP` only) reverse proxy. As a newbie, I am wondering what would I need to modify to make this production ready. Which leads me to the following questions:

- Is there a way to unify the `proxy_set_header` directive so that I don't need to repeat myself for every virtual host?
- Am I missing any other important host header modifications than `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Url-Scheme`, `X-Forwarded-For` and `Host`?

`nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  gzip on;
  # skip log_format/access_log

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server1.company.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://server1;  # IP or FQDN would be better here
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server2.company.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://server2;  # IP or FQDN would be better here
    }
  }
}
```

Any feedback/point to a direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place all of your `proxy_set_header` statements in the `http` block, they will be inherited into the `server` blocks and then into the `location` blocks. The inheritance only happens into blocks without another `proxy_set_header` statement. See [this document](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.

Alternatively, place common statements into a separate file and pull them into any part of your configuration by using an `include` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

Which headers you should set is dependent on your application. But [this article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) discusses preventing certain headers from being passed to the proxied server, e.g.

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

And [this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/) mitigates the HTTPoxy vulnerability with:

```
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
```